# Google Maps iOS issue on Point of interest click

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift4, google-maps-sdk-ios

Hy there I have developed an android app. And in that I have used Google maps. And it is working as expected. In that app, I am showing users the  Point of Interest POI(s). Basically these are small icons over the map.

I am letting user to click on those icons and can save that location for further use. Android version is working as expected.

But when I implemented same logic in the iOS it is not working as it is working in the android. The callback method for swift is as under:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapPOIWithPlaceID placeID: String, name: String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    print(placeID," ",name," ",location.latitude,",",location.longitude )

}
```

**What is happening:**
I can tap on POI icons and it is working fine, but if I click on the place name, it is working like as I am click on POI icon. where as it is not the case with the android version of Google map.. 
I am working on latest versions of Google Map so there is no question of inconsistency.

So I have simple question Does any1 of you face the same situation? and How to stop this behavior of the map in iOS ???

Comment: What do you expect to happen when clicking the name? this sounds more like a difference in implementation between SDK's rather than a coding issue

Comment: the expected behavior should be like its in android. I mean no event is fired when clicking on name or else where in the map. but when you click on the POI icon then the onPoi click event must get fire. In android it is working fine but int he iOS it gets fired even when the user click on the name of location